# Как уменьшить физический размер базы данных mysql (innodb)?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Есть сервер на FreeBSD11 с системой мониторинга Zabbix 3.4 с БД на mysql 5.6.34 (без разбивки по файлам innodb_file_per_table=0). Сейчас БД весит около 90Гб, проверял через

```
SELECT table_schema as `Database`, table_name AS `Table`, 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC
```

Хочу оптимизировать размер БД, удалив устаревшие данные (например, историю состояния хостов). Что нужно сделать после запроса на удаление, чтобы физический размер БД сократился в соответствии с удаленными данными?

Mysql настроен так:

```
[mysqld]
long_query_time = 2
key_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 16M
read_buffer_size = 16M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1048576
max_connections = 2048
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=128M
innodb_file_per_table=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = false
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
sync_binlog = 0
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin
default-storage-engine=INNODB
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

Comment: *Что нужно сделать после запроса на удаление, чтобы физический размер БД сократился в соответствии с удаленными данными?* Найти несколько часов (на глазок - от 2 до 24, как повезёт) для полной остановки сервиса.

Comment: @Akina после полной остановки сервиса, место на диске освободится?

Comment: Не-е-е... эти несколько часов Вы потратите на шринк базы... что при `innodb_file_per_table=0` занятие весьма нетривиальное, так что добавьте ещё и время на полный бэкап.

Comment: @Akina Добавил. А дальше что?

Answer (score 1):

Данные из логов базы надо удалять не по delete, а truncate :)
 Для уменьшения файлов таблиц можно запускать optimize table. это убирает пустое место из файлов таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB не уменьшает свои файлы.
Так что только dump-reinit-restore.